# Design users table for single sign in to use across sub domains

Tags: sql-server, database-design, architecture, database-schema

We have a site which has sub domains like:

1. example.com *-    Main Site*
2. food.example.com
3. fashion.example.com

And each domain and sub domain has a different database, like this:

1. exampleDB *-    Main DB with Users Table*
2. foodDB
3. fashionDB

**What have you tried?**

1. Right now, for single sign in we have planned to redirect users in our Main Site for signing up.
2. While order processing in sub domains get the UserID from main DB and store in respective sub domain's Orders table.
3. For reporting purposes we store the `UserID` without `FK constraint` in the `Orders` table since we have separate database.

I can see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242837/why-does-stack-exchange-use-separate-databases-for-each-network-site) that stack exchange sites have separate databases, but does it have separate [users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103568/how-are-network-site-user-profiles-linked?rq=1) tables too?

**Does StackExchange Network profile is stored in a separate database?**

I can see from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) that Every site's user table has AccountId of StackExchange Network profile.

**An Example:**

1. [Here](https://stackexchange.com/users/7598/nick-craver) is Nick Craver Network Profile with ID:7598
2. His profile in History Site has Account ID Linked with same ID:7598 check [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/history/query/edit/491023#resultSets) query.

I can't see the `Accounts` table anywhere in [data dumbs](https://data.stackexchange.com/) , So Were is `AccountId` stored? And how is SSO done in multiple sites using `AccountId` ?

**My Question:** Do we need a single user table in Main DB or we have to create separate user tables for the sub domain's database and `Link Main DB UserID` but not FK constraint? Which is the best design for a shopping site?

Any help would be great.

Comment: StackExchange uses a different users table for each website.  
You can see for your self that you need to sing up for each website individually and you get a different user id for each website.

Answer (score 5):

The UserID you mentioned is only identical in a specific Users table in a single DB. It's actually not an identifier of any user in your domain. To identify users across multiple databases, you will need a domain-level ID for every user. A simple way is to add one more property (column) named UID or something like that to User class (table), of Global Unique Id (GUID, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) and use it as domain-level ID to identify users instead of UserId. This way you can freely store user information in multiple databases in your domain. So:

- You can hold only domain-level ID in every sub-domain's database and use that ID to query full user profiles from the main domain DB. Pros: costs less memory. Trade-off: in a distributed system, it takes longer to query user information from sub-domain because the information residing in main DB.
- You can hold full user information in all DB, including main's and subs'. Pro: faster queries. Cons: costs more memory and when a user information changes, you will have to synchronize it across all databases.

Comment: suppose i have 4 database for 4 sub domains, and user comes to main domain changes his password, so i have to send request to all 4 databases to sync the new password, is that good practice ?

Comment: No it's not good in terms of SSO. You should store user credentials (username & password) in a central place and provide authentication API so that every website in your domain can use. The API should return an access token representing user upon successful login. The API can also be used for updating credentials. You should store sub-domain-specific user preferences/information in sub-domain's database. E.g: in sub-domain A, user selected a theme and in another sub-domain B, he/she can use a different theme. And the UID I mentioned in my answer above is used to identify user everywhere.

Comment: thanks for responding, but what if main site DB goes down ? how the user can login ?

Comment: It's normal to not allow user to login when the main site is down. Imagine, if Facebook is temporarily down for awhile, any website that uses Facebook authentication will not allow Facebook users to login. The main DB being down can be considered as a scheduled maintenance. You might need to add fail-over cluster support to increase availability of the main DB and avoid unexpected downtime as well.

Comment: we dont have user preferences like theme , we save user email, password, delivery address in main db and the same email, password, delivery address in other DB , so why we need a separate user table for each database ? , any way i have to query the main DB to authenticate the User ?

Comment: It depends on criteria when you design your system. If some information must be identical at all time across all sub-domain, you can store it centrally. Otherwise, if some information allows some delay to be synchronized in all sub-domains, you can keep separate 'copies' of those info in sub-domains' DB as cache. This is helpful for distributed system. Last, do not think of querying main DB to authenticate user. You should develop some API (e.g RESTFul) for that purpose. API provides better control of user 'session' and better scalability, availability and reliability for your entire system.

Comment: ok finally i can use the Main UID off cource not as foreign key for orders table in other databases to take reports ? if yes then i have to do inner joins to main DB user table to get user name, address etc

Comment: I'm not always online. Sorry :-). Yes you can use UID as a reference key to take report. And if you are placing all databases on the same server you can do querying with inner joins. However, this way limits your system's scalability as you will have troubles when you want to separate those DBs onto different servers some day in the future. If you don't bother distributing your system, you can stick to querying with inner joins across databases. Otherwise use API (RESTFul or Web Services).

Answer (score 2):

1] You need to have separate user table in all three database because there is no referential integrity of foreign key.Here if any database goes down, then other domains will up and running.Trade-off is, database management needs more maintenance but performance will not hamper.

Alternatively you can produce following database plan.

1] Keep one database for all three domain(One main domain and two sub domain)

2] Create one user table having two status flag for food_order, fashion_order

3] Create order table for food and fashion separate

4] There are three possibility that user orders i)Food or ii)Fashion or iii)Food/Fashion both.

5] Keep update status flag as per order either Food or Fashion or Food/Fashion both.

Here trade-off is that, if your database goes down, then your all three website goes down.So Keep very good disaster recovery model of database.

Comment: thanks for responding, i have edited my post with how Stack Exchange uses AccoountId, already we have separate databases, we are just trying to integrate SSO and concerned about user table, so i am looking for better solution.

Comment: Keep separate user table in all three database. There is no redundancy as fact data are with different database

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

1. Only store your users in the main DB. Then ...

   - use an encrypted cookie to store all the user information you care about. This cookie would be readable by all the other sub-domains.
   - OR only store the user_id in the cookie and use back channel communication over an API to get the users information from the main site.
   - OR use one of the many existing fairly standard user information sharing protocols to get user information into the other sites, where you can then store it in the current session store. Some examples include CAS and OAuth.
2. Store your user information in all the DBs. You would typically get the information to the other DBs by using one of...

   - regularly scheduled synchronization job
   - back channel communication when the user logs in
   - one of the fairly standard user information sharing protocols (as above)

With option 1, your main DB going down would impact all the other sites. With option 2, the non-main DBs are pretty much cached copies, and you need to  deal with cache invalidation.

Which option you pick will mostly depend on your specific business needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think how you started off in your question is your best bet.

Your best bet is to have one users table, and three configuration tables.  The one users table will be linked to the SSO functionality, which will validate users, their overall profile and credentialing information.  Every service/website irrelevant of the domain which use the federated SSO validating the users cookies.  I.e. pretend everything was the same, except you are using google web federation for SSO.  The data stored in google you don't really care about (except maybe there are field that you do, maybe user name, etc...)  No matter which domain you are on, the first thing you do is make a call to SSO, and see if the user is already logged in, if they aren't direct them there, and when they are done, they will get a redirect back to your subdomain.

If they are logged in, then no redirect, but you get the jwt token, which would allow converting saved userIds (or UID) to actual information.

Say for instanced a logged in user buys something from fashion.example.com.  You could add a row to your orders table, which happens to have a column called "userId".  If that site wanted to publish on the front page "user X ordered Y", after getting the order from the table, you would call the SSO service to get back a jwt with the users information using the SSO token.  If for some reason you wanted to store configuration that is different by subdomain, then that subdomain would create its own "users" or "configuration" table, and the key would be linked to the UID in the SSO service.  Whether there is a unique PK is up to you (with a FX to the UID) or if the PK is the UID.

This let's you completely separate the the domains from each other.  And let's your subdomain decide if they need a "users" table or not.

You really have 4 domains, not 3, treat it as 1 SSO authentication domain and 3 sites.  The SSO will have the auth table, and each site domain may or may not have its own user table if it needs to.  That user table would have an FK to the SSO table, without needing to enforce an FX constraint.  (FK constraint, if somehow could be enforced would actually be bad, because you wouldn't want an SSO service, to have to know about the subdomains when a user's account should be deleted, the fact these are all different database is already awesome.)

And because SSO/user management is really its own domain, that is exactly why there are SaaS solutions that support user management directly, for the explicit reason that this is actually complicated and reimplementing it should be avoided at all costs.

TL;DR. You really have 4 domains, not 3, treat it as 1 SSO authentication domain and 3 sites.  The SSO will have the auth table, and each site domain may or may not have its own user table if it needs to.